# Rails request.original_url is not encode on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, heroku

I have a Rails 4 application deployed in Heroku.

This code:

```
URI(request.original_url)
```

Works great in development, but fails in production with some spacial cases.

If you type "www.example.com/seach/<2>" in the browser, the request is made to "http://www.example.com/seach/%3C2%3E" which is correct.

In development, that code works, but in production it raises:

```
(bad URI(is not URI?): www.example.com/seach/<2>):
```

Which (i guess) means `request.original_url` is not the encoded url im getting in development env.

How can i get the same (encode) url i have in development?
Could it be a heroku problem? nginx?

Thanks

Comment: Try `url` instead of `original_url`.

Comment: It didnt work either